# Android fragments move through the stack

Tags: android, android-fragments

Imagine this: One activity with 5 fragments.

**Fragment1** -> **Fragment2** (fragment1 opens fragment2 and onBackPressed reverses the operation)

**Fragment3** -> **Fragment4**

This works as expected but now I want to do this:

**Fragment5** -> Fragment**4** which works but when I press the onBackPressed() I want to be taken to Fragment3 not Fragment5. And when I get to Fragment3 and press back to exit the app.

I tried to do many things in order to manipulate the backstack. But none of these resolves my problem. I swap the fragments via `transaction.replace(container,myFragment)`.

I've checked the documentation provided, but I cannot seem to find a proper way to manipulate the backstack (or a flag whatsoever)

Comment: don't add fargment 5 in backstack

Comment: I do not use the addToBackStack() method to add the Fragment5 to the backstack.

Comment: Please take a look on "How to add fragment to backtack" or please give more details about fragment switch from where to where

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're switching betweens `Fragments` inside the same `Activity`.

All the `FragmentTransaction` are *addToBackStack* before *commit*. That means you can get how many times the user changed between the `Fragments` using the following method:

```
int count = getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount();
```

In a way you can identify every `Fragment` and do whatever you want.

If you use the solution below you'll notice that `getFragmentManager().popBackStack();` simply makes it return to the previous `Fragment`.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    int count = getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount();

    if (count == 0) {
        super.onBackPressed();
        //additional code
    } else {
        getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
    }

}
```

Comment: What will that code do? Could you please explain a little bit?